# How to bind JSON data to dropdownlist in Asp.net MVC using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to bind JSON Data to dropdown list

My Scenario is I want to get data and Bind to dynamic dropdown list,

In Seperate Class, I have used linq to get data like

```
    public SelectList getProjects()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> projectslist = (from proj in res.PROJECTs where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" select proj).AsEnumerable().Select(projt => new SelectListItem() { Text = projt.NAME, Value = projt.ID.ToString() });
        return new SelectList(projectslist, "Value", "Text", PROJ_ID);
    }
```

In Controller:

```
ViewBag.ProjectList=(from proj in res.PROJECTs where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" select proj).AsEnumerable().Select(projt => new SelectListItem() { Text = projt.NAME, Value = projt.ID.ToString() });
```

In View:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
    {                                    {
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList, "-- Choose a Project --", new { @class = "ddlProjectvalue" })
    }
```

Now, I am trying for like if  we have three dropdownlist, we select a list item in first dropdown list should not show in second dropdown list, and in third dropdown list should not show both previous selected list items for that i have writtern script like:

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ddlProjectvalue').change(function () {
            debugger;
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue != '') {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Employer/GetDDLData?selectedValue="+selectedValue,
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "Json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        // first remove the current options if any
                        $('.ddlProjectvalue').find('option').remove();

                        // next iterate thru your object adding each option to the drop down\    
                        $(data).each(function (index, item) { // GETTING ERROR HERE
                            debugger;

                            $('.ddlProjectvalue').append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
                        });
                    },
                    error: function ajaxError(response) {
                    alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
      });
    });
   </script>
```

and I am returning JSON Data from Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetDDLData(string selectedValue)
    {
        int projectid = Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue);

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> projectslist = (from proj in db.PROJECTs where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" && proj.ID != projectid select proj).AsEnumerable().Select(projt => new SelectListItem() { Text = projt.NAME, Value = projt.ID.ToString() });
        var result = new SelectList(projectslist, "Value", "Text", tm.PROJ_ID);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have tried, but getting Error like

```
      "Syntax error, Unrecognized Expression"
```

where I am Doing Wrong , please help me anyone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will help you :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetDDLData","Employer")",
            data: {selectedValue:selectedValue},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            error: function () {
                alert(" An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var optionhtml1 = '<option value="' +
                 0 + '">' + "--Select State--" + '</option>';
                $(".ddlProjectvalue").append(optionhtml1);

                $.each(data, function (i) {

                    var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                data[i].Value + '">' +data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    $(".ddlProjectvalue").append(optionhtml);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks it was working fine, but small problem as it was dynamic ddl it was effecting three dropdown list, it should not like that! if we select first ddl should not show in second ddl dynamically , and vice versa for total dropdown list, any ideas?, please help me.

Comment: you should provide Id to each of the dropdownlist

Comment: How I can , if we have more than three or four ddls, can we pass id for all and apply our solution to all ddls? or is there any alternative solution for this problem?

Comment: lets try it @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList, "-- Choose a Project --", new { @class = "ddlProjectvalue",@id="dropdown_"+i })

Comment: instead of class name you can use $(this)

Comment: Yes this seems better :)

Comment: it doesn't work, can we some stuff in controller that deletes first time selected value and never repeats again? any ideas?

Comment: If we select first item in first ddl that we have to save and that should not repeat again, is this possible in Controller action method. @Ni3

Comment: you can do it using session

Comment: if we use session , every time session will override, how will it works? @Ni3

Comment: You need to create a session list in which all the projects listed

Comment: in my case :if (Session["CartItems"] == null)
                Session["CartItems"] = new List<SubscriptionCart>(); // Check that it exists
            
            
            List<SubscriptionCart> myList = (List<SubscriptionCart>)Session["CartItems"];
            // Cast and add to your list
            cart.ItemId =myList.Count==0?1:myList.Last().ItemId+1;
            myList.Add(cart);
            Session["CartItems"] = myList; //

Comment: You need to create a list of session that contains ProjectId and ProjectName and you have to call this list inside your View First and after selecting the ddlFirst you need to call $.ajax post action on select event of ddlFirst so that it post the ProjectId of the ddlFirst and this method fetch the project using its id then remove that item from the list and re-assign the list to the session

Answer (score 4):

```
//Controller Code

public ActionResult getAccount()
         {
             var result = new SelectList(db.Partymsts, "Account", "Account");
             return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }

// js code

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/NewMaster/getAccount",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data) {
                var optionhtml1 = '<option value="' +
                 0 + '">' + "--Select State--" + '</option>';
                $(".cs3").append(optionhtml1);

                $.each(data, function (i) {

                    var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                data[i].Value + '">' +data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    $(".cs3").append(optionhtml);
                });
            }
            });


// html code


<select id="cs3" name="cs3"   class="cs3 form-control input-small"> </select>




its working !!
```

Comment: this is the solution of getting empty result. in droupdown list binding. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is correct the below will work.Put the code in your ajax success

```
success:function(data){
 $('.ddlProjectvalue').empty();
 $.each(data,function (index, item) { 
    $('.ddlProjectvalue').append$('<option>', {
                                value: item.Value,
                                text: item.Text
                            }, '<option/>')
                            }
                        );
   }
```

Comment: No, getting Empty result, anyway thanks for solution , i have got in different approach.

Comment: Answer was updated.It must work, if your json is correct.Tell us if there is an error.

Comment: No, it is getting EMpty Result

Comment: Please,Can you show the returned Json? So that other people can get help from it.

Comment: Of you are getting ID and Name as json, then use.  Value:item.ID,text:item.Name

Comment: Return JSON getting same as JSON format only, but I followed approach of @Ni3's solution, you can check above solution.

Comment: $(this) reference doesn't work, can we some stuff in controller that deletes first time selected value and never repeats again? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We have done in this way

`Dropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(item.col1).text(item.col2));`

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetDropDownData(stateid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("getdist","Home")',
            data: {stateid:stateid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#districtId").empty();
                $("#districtId").append('<option value="">--Select--</option>');
                $.each(data, function (id, result) {
                        $("#districtId").append('<option value"'+result.Value+'">'+result.Text+'</option>');
                    });
                },
                failure: function () {
                    $("#districtId").empty();
                    $("#districtId").append('<option value="">--Select--</option>');
                }
            });
    }
```