# Pulling in JSON via AJAX to populate a Drop-Down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am pulling in some JSON data that will vary... for instance:

Data returned could be:

```
[{"userID":"2779","UserFullName":" Absolute Pro-Formance"},{"userID":"2780","UserFullName":" AR Fabrication"},{"userID":"2781","UserFullName":" Banda Lucas Design Group"}]
```

or:

```
[{"orderID":"112958","OrderName":"Order ID: 112958"},{"orderID":"112957","OrderName":"Order ID: 112957"},{"orderID":"112956","OrderName":"Order ID: 112956"}]
```

What I am attempting to do is process this JSON to build a `<select>` list.

```
// Load in a drop-down as JSON
function LoadDropDown($url, $where, $id, $selectName){
    var $loading = '<div class="pageLoader" style="margin:0 auto !important;padding:0 !important;"><img src="/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..." height="11" width="16" /></div>';
    var $t = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var $container = jQuery($where);
    var options = {
            url: $url + '?_=' + $t,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){
                    $container.html($loading);  
                },
            success: function(data, status, jqXhr){
                $html = '<select class="form-control" id="'+$selectName+'" name="'+$selectName+'">';
                $html += '<option value="0">- Select an Option -</option>';
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length-1; ++i) {
                    var item = data[i];
                    console.log(item.userID);
                }
                $html += '</select>';
                $container.html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');
            },
            complete: function(jqXhr, status){},
            error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
                $container.slideDown('fast').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-4x pull-left"></i><p><strong>Danger Will Robinson!</strong><br />There was an issue pulling in this page. Our support team has been notified, please check back later.</p></div>');    
            }
    };
    jQuery.ajax(options);
}
```

The issue I am having is... #1 `console.log(item.userID);` always shows `undefined`, and #2 how can I effecitvely dynamically build the options?  The returned JSON will ALWAYS contain 2 items per `row` and `id`, and a `name`

## UPDATE

```
for(var $key in data){
    var $val = data[$key];
    for($j in $val){
        console.log('name:' + $j + ' = ' + $val[$j]);
    }
}
```

Is showing me what I need in Firefox Console...  But 1 item per line, for each (for example the 1st JSON) `name:userID = 1234` next line `name:UserFullName = TheName`

How can I get them so I can build my `<options>`?

With:

```
for(var k in data) {
    console.log(k, data[k]);
}
```

I am returned:

```
2955 Object { orderID="8508", OrderName="Order ID: 8508"}
```

and

```
2955 Object { userID="1355", UserFulleName="Me Myself And I"}
```

Comment: put dataType:"json" in ajax setup.

Comment: set the dataType option to json in your options, by default it is text/html so your data is just a string

Comment: These are answers, not comments. Feel free to post as such and get some rep!

Comment: I did after I posted the question LOL.   But doesnt really answer the real issue, so may want to revisit...   Since the JSON returned will always contain the 2 objects per element, the element names may not be the same for each pull...  in otherwords, I will probably never know the `names` of the objects returned

Comment: then you can use text and value see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928756/how-to-bind-json-data-to-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-using-jquery/22929084?noredirect=1#comment35007257_22929084

Comment: you will get the idea

Comment: tried that with `console.log('value: ' + data[$i].Value + ' text: ' + data[$i].Text);` and I get `value: undefined text: undefined`  It's because of the key names... I will never know what the key names are, as I've stated... I only KNOW that I will have 2 items per iteration... 1 value, and 1 text.   `p.s.` using `.each` is alot slower

Comment: answer updated, and for the performace issue:if you have 5000 items in the json then comes the performance issue.But dropdown list is not going to have 5000 items in it.So, you can use it.

Comment: actually... the second drop-down I am using this for has 6271 items, the 1st has 7632 items.  Also, have a look at what I posted as an answer as it cured the issue.  I will never know what the keys names are, so your answer is a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cured:  Changed my loop to cycle through each item in the returned JSON, got their keys, etc...

```
var $dl = data.length;
for(var $i = 0; $i < $dl - 1; ++$i) {
    var $keys = Object.keys(data[$i]);
    $html += '<option value="' + data[$i][$keys[0]] + '">' + data[$i][$keys[1]] + '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how this resolved the problem. Don't forget to upvote any answers you found helpful if you haven't already done so, and mark one answer as accepted (there's a 48 hour waiting period if you want to accept your own answer).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use such messy code. Also in your Ajax setup `dataType:"json"`

```
success:function() {
    var listB=$('#yourdropdownId');
    listB.empty();  
    $.each(result, function (index, item) {
        listB.append(
            $('<option>', {
                value: item.userID,
                text: item.UserFullName
            }, '<option/>'))
         });
    }
```

Also the $.getJson instead of ajax if you only want retrieve json from server

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action(" "," ")',
                { "youparametername": yourdata}, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    })
            });
```

Comment: You're right, is a good solution. But it's more slower because you forced jQuery to create and parsed each data. Whereas you could create a string and write all the code like x += '<option value="'+id+'">'+userFullName+'</option>'; and you append x to the DOM directly you will be more faster. But, I already said, your solution is good too.

Comment: @queval_j when using dataType:"json", isn't the data is already parsed to json.But I think you are right on the second opinion of creating a string

Answer (score 1):

inside the options object, make sure to use the

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Or in the success handler you can use

```
JSON.parse(data)
```